# TargetServerUrl where to deploy a ssrs report in Dynamics crm online?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

I created a ssrs report with visual studio for dynamics CRM and when I wanted to deploy it in my online crm, Even I give the URL of my CRM in the TargetServerUrl, the password and username, it asks me always to give the password.
Is there a special form of TargetServerUrl? do you have any idea about the source of this issue?
The TargetServerUrl, I used is dynamics url : https:/company.crm4.dynamics.com

I tried also with this structure: https://company.crm4.dynamics.com/OrgUniqueName

but the visual window asking of password appears always even if the password is correct, when I click on deploy.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you get stuck on this, don't forget you can just upload it through CRM's UI.

Comment: I tried to upload it from CRM but i didnt know how, could you pleased tell me how?

Comment: Go to the reports area click new. http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/robertcooper/2012/04/26/creating_reports_in_microsoft_dynamics_crm_2011